# How ro retrieve a failed hadoop reduce task, use successful map computation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

There is a hadoop map-red job on a large amount of data. The map phase takes a long time to complete (~2-3 days). It completed.

But the task failed at ~92% in the reduce phase. Is it possible to retrieve the output/computations performed by the successful map tasks so that only reduce phase may need to be re-run?

Running Hadoop 1.2.1, Java7, Single node linux system.

Answer (score 0):

No this isn't possible. If the logic of your mapper is computationally intensive (instead of IO heavy) you can either multithread using the [MultithreadedMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/MultithreadedMapper.html%20MultithreadedMapper) or try to split your job into two jobs. The second job would then just "indentity map" the output of the longer running previous job.